How do I create formula input blocks in PyQt6?
Word has the ability to create formulas thanks to the constructor, I want to repeat a similar interface, but I can't figure out how to create the same cell blocks for data entry:

I want to implement such blocks in PyQt6, but I don't know how to approach it. The application should be able to provide different blocks similar to those in Word. At the same time, so that you can get the value from such blocks, for example in this form: {(dx)/(dx)}

Sorry but somebody approved your post quite superficially. As already suggested in the Staging Ground, we do not provide answers to broad questions asking how to approach such a generic problem. Please read the given suggestions, and eventually [edit] your post with a proper [mre] and appropriate explanation of your issues, but only if you did try to achieve what you want. If you didn't, then sorry, but your question doesn't meet StackOverflow requirements. Please read [ask] and review the checklist.
